# How can I create hybrid apps on IOS?

Tags: ios, accessibility, hybrid

I see on Android that apps exist to create android apps. I understand nothing like this exists on IOS because of apple's terms. On IOS however, some apps, pythonista for example, allow the user to create scripts that run similar to apps. Is this functionality currently available for hybrid frameworks, IE phonegap/cordova, react native, etc? Barring this, is there some method whereby I can code and test such apps on my iPhone/iPad?

Bottom line, I want to code apps while commuting, etc, on IOS. I understand I need a computer to compile the final product, that's ok, it's just the coding/testing process I want to do on IOS.

I am up for any hack you can think of to make this work, so long as it is accessible with VoiceOver, apple's screen reader, as I cannot see at all. One example of something I thought of that won't work is using remote desktop software, there is no such software that is accessible as it uses an image of the remote screen, I have no access to this.

I am looking forward to your creativity, so far this has me stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pythonista is kind of a miracle. To try to do something similar is a huge commitment. Good luck.

Comment: So I am discovering. Apple loves to say iPad can replace a laptop, guess this situation is one more bit of proof to the contrary. Still hoping though.

Comment: I have a wild question: As you cannot see, are there mods of Macs, with a removed screen? You could use headphones and the bottom part of a MacBook Air shouldn't be heavier than an iPad.

Comment: Some time ago, you could write iOS-App in Pythonista and export it as an Xcode project. But I think Ole Zorn removed that feature because it did not work properly.

Comment: This would be cool, but leads to problems. On the macbook air, you could never "sleep" it, as soon as you bumped a key or the trackpad, it would wake. Closest is a mac mini, but Mac OS runs slo if nothing is connected. There are devices that can be plugged in for headless mac mini's, this is good, it's cheeper than buying a monitor. Win10, by the way has no prob running headless as long as a vid card. Used to be a company, laptalk, that made screenless winXP laptops, but they're out of business. They charged four times the value.

Comment: I believe pythonista offers an xcode template, this seems like my best option. I like html because it's easy to design the ui, everything is text, pythonista uses a visual designer, it seems accessible, it's probably very precise if you can see, but not so much for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the playgrounds answer, but if you wanted to use Xamarin you could use Continuous .NET. It’s a C# IDE for iOS. You could then use Working Copy to to keep the version on your computer in line.

The other option is to VNC into your computer at home, but if you’re on the train that might not be a great option.

Comment: Continuous.net looks interesting, Dr. Google didn't suggest this in my many web searches. Kinda broke, so I can't test it until next month, but it looks good. If nothing better is suggested in the next day or so, I'll accept this answer. THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution for your problem, but if you have an iPad, you can write parts of apps in Swift Playgrounds. There you have access to all the UIKit stuff. Unfortunately some of the frameworks you can use in iOS are missing.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea, as you say, it's not quite what I'm looking for, but it's a good start.